# Cannot bypass [SequelizeConnectionError]: unable to get local issuer certificate using ssl: { require: true, rejectUnauthorized: false,}

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js

using the following Sequelize connection parameters:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
  process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        'Amazon RDS': {
          require: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          authPlugins: {
            mysql_clear_password: () => () => signer.getAuthToken(),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
);
```

running `node server.js` yields:

```
Server is running on port 8080.
Unable to create table :  ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/Path/To/Project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)

 at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12) {
    code: 'HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR',
    fatal: true
  },

Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'saves' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_schema'
Connection has been established successfully.
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `saves`
Saves table created successfully!
```

when I attempt to access any routes on the server it returns the message

```
{"message":"unable to get local issuer certificate"}
```

Per the suggestions of other posts, I have tried passing

```
  ssl:{
          require: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
}
```

in the Sequelize config params.

I have also tried

`export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'`
before running node server.js

and using:

sslmode=no-verify.

None of these workarounds seem to work, and even if they did, I'd prefer not to compromise security by not verifying certificates.  Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here?